Audio Playback Issues in Ubuntu
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS and I am experiencing a weird audio playback issue. When playing any audio (Spotify, YouTube, or a video file on VLC), it will not play any audio. No errors are shown, and I have tried it across multiple browsers and applications (Firefox, Chrome, etc.)
What is stranger, is that if I mute the audio and then unmute, it will temporarily solve the issue for a few seconds or a few minutes. But then the audio will suddenly halt and I won't be able to resume.
I tried the fix shown in Ubuntu's stopped playing music/video files & Youtube but it didn't work.
I resorted to uninstalling pulseaudio from my machine and re-installing it, but the problem still persists occasionally.
When re-installing pulseaudio, I had to kill and restart the plasmashell service and I finally found an error associated when the audio playback issue occurs. When I run plasmashell the following errors appear when I hit the play button on a YouTube video (or Spotify song, or video with VLC) and it refuses to play:
QObject::disconnect: Unexpected nullptr parameter
QObject::disconnect: Unexpected nullptr parameter

I am at a loss of what could be the problem here and how to fix it. The issue is intermittent ever since I re-installed pulseaudio, but it is still annoying.
